# Linear algebra, inner product, idempotent, Proof of L=projW

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, that $L:V\to V$ is an idempotent linear map, and that The vector space $W=Range(L)$.

Prove that there is an inner product on $V$ with the property that $L=proj_{W}$

Comment: I have been on this for a long time, and here are my thoughts and progress. I don't understand the mechanisms of some parts, and I need a little help to finish this proof.

Since $W=Range(L)$, then there is some vector $v$ in $V$ such that $L(\vec{v})=\vec{w}$ where $\vec{w}$ is in $W$. 
Let $\vec{x},\vec{y}$ in $W$, so $$\vec{x}=c_{1}\vec{w}_{1}+...+c_{k}\vec{w}_{k}+d_{k+1}\vec{v}_{k+1}+...+d_{n}\vec{v}_{k+1}$$

Comment: $$\vec{y}=c_{1}\vec{w}_{1}+...+c_{k}\vec{w}_{k}+f_{k+1}\vec{v}_{k+1}+...+f_{n}\vec{v}_{k+1}$$ then $$L(\vec{x})=?\vec{w}_{1}+...+?\vec{w}_{k}$$  $$L(\vec{y})=?\vec{w}_{1}+...+?\vec{w}_{k}$$
How do you figure out ? that is equal to ..., I am stuck here, feel free to give any suggestions.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3869109/81360).

Comment: Yeah, but that proof is far from the answer that I need to do, but it does give me something, why the polynomial is in that proof? There is no need.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that there is "no need". Also, why is this "far from the answer that you need to do"? Do you understand that this question is exactly the same as yours?

Comment: Yes, but the answer does not seem to make sense at all. Can you explain to me a little bit? Do you understand it?

Comment: Yes, I understand it. I'll give an alternative explanation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115330/discussion-between-logan-and-ben-grossmann).

Answer (score 0):

We are given that $L$ is idempotent, which is to say that $L^2 = L$.

**Claim:** $L$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $0,1$.

**Proof:** Note that any vector $x \in V$ can be decomposed as
$$
x = Lx + (x - Lx).
$$
we note that $L(Lx) = L^2x = Lx$, so that $Lx$ is an eigenvector associated with $\lambda = 1$. $L(x - Lx) = Lx - L^2x = 0$, so that $(x - Lx)$ is an eigenvector associated with $\lambda = 0$. Since every vector can be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors, $L$ is diagonalizable. $\square$

Now, there is nothing to be done in the case where the only eigenvalue is $1$ ($L$ is the identity map) or the only eigenvalue is $0$ ($L$ is the zero map). For the remaining cases, let $\mathcal B$ be a basis such that the matrix of $L$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is
$$
[L]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & 0},
$$
where $I$ denotes an identity matrix. Define an inner product over $V$ by
$$
\langle v, w \rangle = [v]_{\mathcal B} \cdot [w]_{\mathcal B},
$$
where $[v]_{\mathcal B}$ denotes the coordinate vector of $v$ relative to $\mathcal B$, and $\cdot$ denotes a dot-product. It remains to be shown that this is an inner product and that relative to this inner product, $L$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: I still don't get it. From the very beginning. What is x? I don't think eigenvalues are part of "my proof"  Maybe this proof is correct, but not helpful to me at all. Can you look at my thoughts above? Thank you.

Comment: @Logan $x$ is an arbitrary vector in $V$. As for your thoughts, it is difficult for me to understand what you have written, let alone make it into a complete proof. For example, what exactly are the vectors $\vec w_1,\dots, \vec w_k$, and what are the vectors $\vec v_{k+1}, \dots, \vec{v}_n $?

Comment: I think the proof in another link just make sense a little bit. How does the kernel of L works here? do you know?

Comment: @Logan No problem. Not sure what you mean by "how the kernel of $L$ works here." Are you asking what the "kernel" of a linear transformation is?

Comment: The inner product defined on V  is $$\langle w_1+k_1,w_2+k_2\rangle_V \doteq \langle w_1,w_2\rangle_W + \langle k_1,k_2\rangle_{\ker L},$$ I think this does make sense a little, but I don't understand it somehow. Then why kernel is here and how does that prove L=projW?

Comment: @Logan What makes $L$ the projection is that $x - Lx$ is orthogonal to $Lx$. Note that $Lx$ is an element of $w$, and $Lx - x$ is an element of the kernel of $L$ since $L(Lx - x) = L^2x - Lx = 0$. Because of the way that the inner product is constructed, $Lx - x$ will indeed be orthogonal to $Lx$ since one is an element of the kernel and the other is an element of $W$.